# How do I get local time in another timezone in dot net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, timezone, datetimeoffset

I'm working on a problem in which I need to get the current date and time in another timezone. I don't know what timezone my code will be run on, and it needs to work on both windows and linux machines.

I have not found any way of doing this. Any ideas?

(P.S: I specifically need to find what time it is in Sweden including daylight savings from any arbitrary timezone the code might be running in).

Comment: I generally use UTC for all my DateTime timestamps. If you want to find out the time in a specific time zone, you can take a look at using the built-in Timezone convert methods. You can record time in UTC and then convert as needed. Here's a link to the docs section. You'll have to read up on it and you might have to create your own TimeZoneInfo classes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: I have UTC times for all timestamps, I need this for a message template which includes the current time that is being sent out to clients. The time should be in their local Timezone, and not in UTC. So far I have not found any way to convert a UTC time to another in dot net core. All you find when looking for it is a bunch of posts about it not working the same on windows and linux

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The IANA time zone ID for Sweden is `"Europe/Stockholm"` (for use on Linux, OSX, and other non-Windows platforms).  The Windows time zone ID for Sweden is `"W. Europe Standard Time"`.

Thus, you can do the following:

```
// Determine the time zone ID for Sweden
string timeZoneId = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)
    ? "W. Europe Standard Time"
    : "Europe/Stockholm";

// Get a TimeZoneInfo object for that time zone
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);

// Convert the current UTC time to the time in Sweden
DateTimeOffset currentTimeInSweden = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, tzi);
```

If desired, you can simplify this by using my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library, which allows you to use either id on any platform.

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("Europe/Stockholm");
DateTimeOffset currentTimeInSweden = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, tzi);
```

If running on .NET 6 or newer, and you have [ICU globalization support](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu) enabled, you no longer need to use my library.  .NET will automatically convert from one format to the other if needed.  So you can just do:

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Europe/Stockholm");
DateTimeOffset currentTimeInSweden = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, tzi);
```

Also note that the time zone where the code is running is not relevant, nor should it be.  The daylight savings rules of *Sweden* are the only that are relevant, not those of the time zone where the code might be running in.

Lastly, note that the computer's clock must be set correctly if you expect to get a valid result.  Always synchronize your computer's clock to the Internet by using NTP or your OS's "Set date and time automatically" feature.

Comment: Also note if you're using the .net core Alpine Linux based Docker images, you'll need to install tzdata separately.  See https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/1366

Comment: I'm sorry to downvote the answer of someone who has such high reputation but I don't think this answer is complete or I'm not understanding it correctly. I'm in France, I set my computer's time to one hour earlier than it should (that's my actual issue on the servers where it's deployed). I got the Paris timezone, converted it to DateTimeOffset as in your example and then checked the local datetime. It's one hour earlier than it is really. Also the UTC time is one hour earlier than it actually is. How to get the REAL local time without being based on the computer's time? Sorry but I'm confused

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL - If the clock is set an hour earlier, that's a problem.  Clocks should always be synchronized.  Always use the "Set date and time automatically" (NTP) feature of your operating system if you expect to be able to accurately get the current time using the `Now` or `UtcNow` methods of the platform.  If you cannot rely on the system clock, for whatever reason, you would have to get the current time from a server somewhere you trust.  You could implement an NTP client in your code, or get the current time from a web server if you don't need it to be too precise.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I gave you an upvote instead. Actually the server's time isn't set incorrectly. It's just set on `Europe/London` (the server can be located anywhere in the world) while our business is located in France. I think the confusion came from the name of your variable `currentTimeInSweden`. I was expected the local time to be the Swedish one but actually it's still set to the current machine's time. Anyway I then figured out the property `DateTime` gives the correct date and time so that's fine. Thanks for your answer and sorry for the downvote.

Comment: Hi @JérômeMEVEL.  I think perhaps there's still some confusion to resolve. 
 `currentTimeInSweden` will indeed be the correct time in Sweden, represented as a `DateTimeOffset`.  Accessing the `DateTime` property will just drop the offset and set the `Kind` property of the result to `Unspecified`.  The date and time will be the same.  Also, this code will provide the same output running on a computer located anywhere in the world, as long as that computer's clock is set correctly.

Comment: I think perhaps you may be setting your server's clocks ahead or behind by an hour instead of keeping them synchronized to an NTP source.  If you're setting the time manually in an attempt to adjust for time zone or summer time (DST), that's the wrong approach.  In other words if you just do `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow)`, that should *always* align with the time shown here: https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc