# How to get datetime based on timezone offset in c#?

Tags: c#, timezone

In c#, I do this

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss")
```

but it gets me the server time. However I also have the offset in this format for example `"-04:00"`. How can I combine the offset to get the local time?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your code, which handles the offset? You can add or subtract the offset value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean that you want to get the server's system local time including offset, then use the [`DateTimeOffset.Now`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.now) property.  Then format it as desired.

```
DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz")
```

[The `zzz` specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#zzzSpecifier) produces the offset as a string in the ISO 8601 extended format, that you asked for.

If what you mean is you have a UTC offset from elsewhere and you want to apply it to the current UTC time from the server, then do the following instead:

```
TimeSpan offset = TimeSpan.Parse("-04:00");
DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToOffset(offset);
string result = now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz");
```

This takes the current server time, and applies the [`ToOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tooffset) function to adjust to the offset you provided.

Do keep in mind though that an offset is not the same as a time zone.  The offset you have *might* be the one for the current date and time, or it might be for some other date and time in that time zone.  For example, US Eastern Time is UTC-4 during daylight saving time, but UTC-5 during standard time.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: The issue is the offset is provided by the client like `"-04:00"` and it is different than the system timezone, so I need to factor that in.

Comment: @omega Matt's answer is still the correct one. Both DateTime and DateTimeOffse can parse that offset format just fine. `DareTimeOffset` is *not* limited to the system timezone, it stores the offset explicitly

Comment: From the client, I get the timezone offset from javascript `new Date()`, does that take into account the daylight savings you mention at the end?

Comment: If you are doing `new Date().getTimeZoneOffset()` - that will be the *current* offset.  You can apply it to "now" as above, but you can't simply store it in a database and use it over again to apply to different datetimes.  A more comprehensive approach would be to get the user's IANA time zone ID from the browser with `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`.  Store that string.  Use it either with the `System.TimeZoneInfo` object and my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library, or use it with [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/).

Comment: Example I posted yesterday showing how to use an IANA time zone ID in C# to get the current time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62761358/634824

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint I didn't use `new Date().getTimeZoneOffset()` as that gives me 240. It is positive, so I'm not sure if I should be dividing by -60 to get the `-04:00`. I instead did new Date.toString() and then parsed out the `-04:00`.

Comment: `toString` output isn't standardized.  You shouldn't parse it.  Yes, you would divide by `-60`, as the offset from `getTimeZoneOffset` is in minutes and inverted.  (Keep in mind there are fractional offsets, so don't round or truncate.)  But either way, when getting the *current* offset from the browser, that does take into account daylight saving - but only for the *current* date and time in that time zone.  For example, in New York, it's currently `-04:00` but in December it will be `-05:00`.  So instead of getting an offset, get `"America/New_York"`.

Comment: When I try it I get `America/Toronto`, however when I pass that to c# `FindSystemTimeZoneById` it says `'The time zone ID 'America/Toronto' was not found on the local computer.'.

Comment: Right. `America/Toronto` is an IANA time zone identifier.  To use it on Windows, you'll need to convert it to a Windows time zone identifier (`Eastern Standard Time` in that case).  The easiest way is with [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter)'s `TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo` method, which gives a `TimeZoneInfo` object directly so you don't have to think about the conversion step.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(DateTimeOffset.Parse("01/01/0001 00:00:00 -04:00").Offset.TotalHours).ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss",CultureInfo. InvariantCulture);
```

Need to add the directive

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Comment: how can you convert the `"-04:00"` to -4?

Comment: needs to be `DateTime.UtcNow`

Comment: whats the `.CultureInfo. InvariantCulture` for?

Comment: Its the FormatProvider for the [DateTime.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(DateTimeOffset.Parse("01/01/0001 00:00:00 -04:00").Offset.TotalHours).ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss")
```

Comment: By accident only. First, this is a localized format, this will fail if the server locale doesn't match it. Never mind the US vs EU difference. C# has a specific DateTimeOffest type for working with offsets. You should use the ISO8601 format to avoid failures or worse, incorrect dates. `4/7` can bean April 7th or July 4th